# Wrap text in a list within a QGIS form

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have some long text items in a form such as

1. Which building in Cairns was constructed during 1929-30 and later transformed into a library after the construction of new council offices in 1998?
2. Which building in Cairns was constructed in the early 20th century and is associated with the Cairns City Council and the Cairns community, illustrating the development of local government in the region?

But they show as

[image]

Is it possible to wrap the text or do I need to reduce each question to X characters? I also want this to work in QField.

The data is available in https://app.qfield.cloud/a/fungisfnq/FungisSpatailOlympics2023/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the subject of a current enhancement request. See [here](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/4309)